# Class.forName() throw notFoundException with "*.class" file

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

i've got a problem.. I try to use the reflexion in java

`Class classe = Class.forName((newStringBuilder()).append("Available.CesarCode").toString());`

but this throw an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Available.CesarCode
```

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziBlT.png)

the ".class" file is situated in Available folder

Thanks for your quick response

Comment: did the CesarCode class contains the "package Available;" as the 1st statement? Putting a class to a folder is not enough to make that class part of the package

Comment: Is the folder containing `Available/CesarCode.class` part of the classpath?

Comment: Why isn't the Java code in `src/main/java`? or if you only have the .class file, why is it in `src`?

Comment: I have one too: why `(newStringBuilder()).append("Available.CesarCode").toString()` and not just the string? And the architecture picture does not help since the .class file is not being displayed (and probably not in the src folder either)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger that looks like decompiled code

Comment: For the first, i havn't the ".java" file, i only have ".class". In fact, i must execute a method from this ".class" file.

Secondly, how to put Available/CesarCode.class in part of the classpath?

Thanks

Comment: then decompile it and look again at the 1st statement. You can not put a .class anywhere and hope it will work. The folder tree is significant when dealing with classpath, and *must* match what is written in the source code/byte code. Directive "package" is not just for fun. Then to use a folder as an additionnal classpath root, and depending on the way you run your application, you may consider using the option "cp" of the java command: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the full classpath. For example, "com.alabala.available.CesarCode"